# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'. Kotlin error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

i'm tired to signin .aab file for upload google play console. i can build apk without any issue, but while i'm going to signin .aab file, it's showing error... please see the logcat below.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> Failed to create directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\release'

* Try:
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create directory 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\release'
at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:318)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.ensureOutput(CreateOutputsStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.lambda$execute$0(CreateOutputsStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitOutputProperties(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

how i can fix this issue? please check my build.gradle file below -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "org.jmailen.kotlinter"
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.klepon.wallet"
        minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

def isNonStable = { String version ->
    def stableKeyword = ['RELEASE', 'FINAL', 'GA'].any { it -> version.toUpperCase().contains(it) }
    def regex = /^[0-9,.v-]+(-r)?$/
    return !stableKeyword && !(version ==~ regex)
}

tasks.named("dependencyUpdates").configure {
    // Example 1: reject all non stable versions
    rejectVersionIf {
        isNonStable(it.candidate.version)
    }
}
ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'chip-navigation-bar'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation'
    libraryName = 'Chip Navigation Bar'
    artifact = 'chip-navigation-bar'

    libraryDescription = 'An android navigation bar widget'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.3.4'

    developerId = 'ismaeldivita'
    developerName = 'Ismael Di Vita'
    developerEmail = 'ismaeldivita@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'MIT License'
    licenseUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar/master/LICENSE'
    allLicenses = ['MIT']
}
dependencies {

    // for testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${versions.junit}"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'



    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${versions.kotlin}"

    // support libraries
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    // architecture components
    // Room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.6'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"

    // coroutine
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
    implementation project(':chip-navigation-bar')

    // ktx
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    // networking
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${versions.okhttp}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${versions.okhttp}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${versions.retrofit}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${versions.retrofit}"

    // other dependencies
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${versions.timber}"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${versions.gson}"
    implementation "com.robinhood.spark:spark:${versions.spark}"
    implementation "com.github.midorikocak:currency-picker-android:${versions.currencyPicker}"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:${versions.lottie}"
    implementation("com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:${versions.materialdate}") {
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
    }
    implementation "com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:${versions.pageindicator}@aar"

    // image loading
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.1.0")

    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${versions.stetho}"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:${versions.stetho}"

    implementation "com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:${versions.bottomNav}"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0'


    // epoxy
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy:4.2.0'
    kapt 'com.airbnb.android:epoxy-processor:4.2.0'

    // test
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.2'



    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation project(':crypto-java')


}

kotlinter {
    indentSize = 4
    reporters = ['checkstyle', 'plain']
    experimentalRules = false
    disabledRules = ["no-wildcard-imports"]
}
```

here is build.gradle for navigation -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 32
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all {
        enabled = false
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'chip-navigation-bar'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation'
    libraryName = 'Chip Navigation Bar'
    artifact = 'chip-navigation-bar'

    libraryDescription = 'An android navigation bar widget'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.3.4'

    developerId = 'ismaeldivita'
    developerName = 'Ismael Di Vita'
    developerEmail = 'ismaeldivita@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'MIT License'
    licenseUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar/master/LICENSE'
    allLicenses = ['MIT']
}

dependencies {

    ext {
        kotlinStd = '1.3.31'
        appcompat = '1.1.0'
        constraint = '2.0.0-beta8'
        testJunit = '1.1.1-alpha02'
        testEspresso = '3.1.1'
        testRunner = '1.1.1'
        testArchComponent = '2.0.0'
        kakao = '2.0.0'
    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinStd"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunner"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:$testRunner"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$testArchComponent"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$testJunit"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$testJunit"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$testEspresso"
    androidTestImplementation "com.agoda.kakao:kakao:$kakao"
    
}

apply from: '../publish.gradle'
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you tried invalidating, gradlew cleaning and/or changing output directory?

Comment: yes, i also follow those step but not working.

Comment: any one is here to help me?